# How to write a type safe no-op function in Scala?

Tags: scala

Considering this declaration:

```
def ignore[U](f: => U):U = ???
```

Is it possible to complete this declaration so that the `ignore` function completely ignores the parameter `f` (doing nothing) but still compiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in fact, in scala 2.10, what you have right now compiles, since `???` throws a NotImplementedException.

as @connordoyle points out, a non-throwing implementation is welcome to *not* execute `f`:

```
scala> def ignore[U >: Null](f: => U):U = null
ignore: [U >: Null](f: => U)U

scala> ignore { println("hi"); "yes" }
res11: String = null
```

Comment: Using println can be a bad idea, especially when debugging, because it will take forever to hit a breakpoint that has a specific condition, since println will be printing too much.

Answer (score 2):

The definition already compiles because `???` is of type `Nothing`, which is the bottom type and therefore conforms to the type parameter `U`.

If you want a default value, the usual idiom is:

```
scala> def ignore[U](f: => U):U = null.asInstanceOf[U]
```

But maybe you're wondering why `-Xlint` doesn't complain about unused function parameters.

I wonder that, too.

The doc from `scalac -Y` says `-Ywarn-unused` warns about locals, but it doesn't seem to.

```
$ scala -Xlint -Xfatal-warnings 
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-RC1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class X { private val x = 7 }
defined class X

scala> :se -Ywarn-unused:true

scala> class X { private val x = 7 }
<console>:7: warning: private val in class X is never used
       class X { private val x = 7 }
                             ^
error: No warnings can be incurred under -Xfatal-warnings.

scala> class X { def f = { val x = 7 ; 5 }
     | }
defined class X
```

Update:

To clarify, or muddify,

```
scala> class Y { def test(a: String, b: String) {  val b = "foo"; val c = "bar" ; println(s"$a, $b") } }
<console>:10: warning: local val in method test is never used
```

Comment: It doesn't warn about unused method parameters because it's crazy noisy. It turns out there are tons of methods which have empty implementations like "def logError(msg: String, t: Throwable): Unit = ()".

Comment: @extempore I'll try whether the long shadow is enough hint to trigger the warn usefully. Also, I wonder if sbt could have "focus": only show warns for units I'm working on, even when you compile the world. I don't care about warns for code I'm not fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible, you could just produce an instance of `U` by any other means.